# How to check Oracle Java version if multiple versions of Java installed on Ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu

I have both *OpenJDK* and *Oracle Java* installed on my Ubuntu. 
If the activated java is OpenJDK, is there a way to check the version of Oracle java in bash shell?

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: yes, you need to know the install path of the oracle one. then `/path/to/there/bin/java -version`. Assume that the openjdk one is your default java.

Comment: the output is the verison of openjdk java.

Comment: yes, thanks. /path/to/oracle/java -version does it.

Comment: @user1558064 ok then I post it as answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`update-java-alternatives -l` will list all the java versions installed via the alternatives system.

For instance on one of my systems it will display the version and the path:

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-7-oracle 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

If you want the oracle one then I guess you could do:

```
update-java-alternatives -l | grep oracle | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

This would alternatively find all oracle versions and issue the `-version` command against each one in the list:

```
update-java-alternatives -l | grep oracle | awk '{system($3"/bin/java -version")}'
```

Output may look something like this:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

One step further would be to parse out the java version from the `-version` command and simply display it:

```
(update-java-alternatives -l | grep oracle | awk '{system(""$3"/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep \"java version\"")}') | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

The `2>&1` is needed because Java will display version to standard error. The output would simply look like this (and could be easily assigned to a bash variable if you needed it that way):

```
1.7.0_67
```

If you had multiple oracle instances this would display the version for each one. If you wanted to find all the versions for every Java you could simply remove the `| grep oracle`

Comment: great, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need to do in my bash script. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. I made one last edit that may make using it in Bash a bit easier.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the openjdk java, then the oracle Java in your PC is just a folder. There is no command to check the version of that if you are not using it.

If you once used oracle java then it must be in your java alternatives and you can find the folder (usually with version in name) with:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

If it says something like **/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java**, then you have 1.8 in your pc.

If you haven't used oracle java anytime you simply have to check what you have downloaded.

If you want to simply see the version **you are using:**

```
java -version
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

yes, you need to know the install path of the oracle one. then `/path/to/there/bin/java -version`. Assume that the `openjdk` one is your default java.

Answer (score 2):

you should  follow  bellow  two commands

1. sudo update-alternatives --config java

In their   show the all already installed Java versions  like below[image]

2.gedit ~/.bashrc

`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/folder

## usually /usr/java/jdk or /usr/lib/java/jdk

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

add to bash

Answer (score 1):

Go to the installation folder of the oracle Java, and then open the `bin` folder. Now open a terminal "here" and type `java -version`

alternativelly,
 paste the entire path to that bin folder in the command line followed by `java -version` i.e. `/path/to/bin/java -version`